# Looking for Unstructured Grid Generation Algorithm with Variable Density Triangulation

Tags: algorithm, mesh

I'm looking for a mesh generation algorithm that generates an unstructured grid with multiple points of higher-density triangulation. This is kind of what I'm looking for, without the blank spots with no triangulation:

[image]
[image]

If you don't know the name of a specific algorithm for this purpose, do you perhaps know what keywords I can use to search for what I'm looking for? Also, I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask. If there is another exchange I might find better help in, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at the [Gmsh source code](http://gmsh.info/#Download) so see which algorithm is used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generate a non-uniform mesh is to first scatter points randomly according to some probability distribution and then somehow relax their positions to obtain a mesh of good quality. A simple yet effective algorithm is described in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0036144503429121) by P.-O.Persson and G.Strang.

> Creating a mesh is the first step in a wide range of applications, including scientific computing and computer graphics. An unstructured simplex mesh requires a choice of meshpoints (vertex nodes) and a triangulation. We want to offer a short and simple Matlab code, described in more detail than usual, so the reader can experiment (and add to the code) knowing the underlying principles. We find the node locations by solving for equilibrium in a truss structure (using piecewise linear force-displacement relations) and reset the topology by the Delaunay algorithm. The geometry is described implicitly by its distance function. In addition to being much shorter and simpler than other meshing techniques, our algorithm typically produces meshes of very high quality. We discuss ways to improve the robustness and the performance, but our aim here is simplicity. Readers can download (and edit) the codes from http://math.mit.edu/~persson/mesh.

Full text is available [here](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/persson04mesh.pdf).

Comment: thanks! i think this might be what i'm looking for.